# How to record line-in on MacOS Catalina?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, catalina

Way back then on my Macbook Pro mid-2009, I could record line-in, simply by changing the sound output.

Now, I'm using a Macbook Pro mid-2012, and I can't seem to find a way to switch from the built-in internal microphone to line-in.

I tried to use the software Hijack but it only shows the same input I see in Preferences.

Can someone tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

I reset VRAM/PRAM and now it shows "external microphone (mic port)".